# Syntax error in LEFT JOIN

Tags: postgresql

My query is as below:

```
Select 
    array_to_string(r.media,',') AS service_type,
               array_to_string(array_agg(distinct s.state_name), ',') as primary_location 
   FROM contract.contract c
   LEFT JOIN customer.customer_state s , contract.rights r ON s.id = ANY (r.state) 
    WHERE c.customer_code::text = 'YYYY'::text 
  group by r.state 
  order by c.contract_name asc;
```

and I'm getting:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 44:    LEFT JOIN
>   customer.customer_state s , contract.rights r O...

Please suggest

Comment: The error message states that error is `at or near "," LINE 44`. I do not see 44 lines in your query. Please post full query

Comment: BTW I do not see a join predicate between `contract.contract` and `customer.customer_state`. You need `LEFT JOIN customer.customer_state s ON %something%`

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what it's supposed to do, though thankyou for showing the exact query text and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix explicit and implicit joins like that.

```
FROM contract.contract c
LEFT JOIN customer.customer_state s , contract.rights r ON
                                  ^^^
```

You should use explicit `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` terms if you're going to be including `LEFT JOIN` terms.

The predicate for a join must always immediately follow the join, without other extras.

If you want to do a left join on multiple tables, you must chain the left joins.

```
FROM contract.contract c
LEFT JOIN customer.customer_state s ON (...)
LEFT JOIN contract.rights r ON (...)
```

---

Guesswork from here on in, as the original query's intent is unclear.
Perhaps you mean

```
FROM contract.contract c
INNER JOIN customer.customer_state s ON (...??...)
LEFT JOIN contract.rights r ON (s.id = ANY (r.state))
```

though I don't see any predicate that connects `contract` to either `rights` or `customer_state` in the original, so it's hard to guess your intent. If you actually intended a cartesian product (cross join) you'd write:

```
FROM contract.contract c
CROSS JOIN customer.customer_state s
LEFT JOIN contract.rights r ON (s.id = ANY (r.state))
```